# Algorithm to analyse photoplethysmogram (PPG) signal in python

Tags: python, signal-processing

I want to calculate the Heart Rate Variability using a PPG. I have the raw PPG values and I actually don't know where to go.

I would like to be able to do this in Python. If anyone could be me the steps to doing this it would be great.

Cheers in advance[image: sample PPG]

Comment: What form do the values take?

Comment: The values that I have are integer numbers and the units are mV. The sampling rate is 256Hz. 
An example of the numbers
(2324,2108,1897,1796,1711,1646,1596,1559,1622,1673,1725,1762,1792,1813,1829,1842,1854,1863,1870,1878,1886,1892,1899,1907,1914,1919,1923,1929,1934,1938,1944,1949,1954,1960,1968,1972,1979,1984,1989,1995,1998,2005,2011,2014)

Comment: When you say analyse, do you mean frequency or time domain? Or something else?

Comment: Or maybe you just want to identify the peaks? In which case, you could look at https://blog.ytotech.com/2015/11/01/findpeaks-in-python/.

Comment: Well ultimately what I want is the following: Heart Rate (finding the peaks) and Heart Rate Variability. What I have to first though is clean up the signal. I know I would have to run some filters on the data but I come from a more maths background than a CS background and don't know a whole lot about signal processing.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this query: (1) it's too broad for SO in that it now touches upon how to filter the data as well as how to do some statistical analysis on the filtered data; (2) it's not about programming at all in that we normally accept queries in which someone offers code which has some specific programming problem. I think you need to begin by identifying the applicable mathematics, then write up some (Python?) code that attempts to do that, and then asking for help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried [HeartPy](https://python-heart-rate-analysis-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ?

In this library should be tools to analyze the PPG curve in both time and frequency domain